# android add map with transparent buttons on top programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, android-maps

i want to add at run time a Map and some **transparent(as in map visible underneath)** buttons to controll the type of map shows(normal/satellite/traffic).

I can do it with xml like

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
<map>
<button .../>
<button .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However since i want to select api key based on debug/release i can't get the map to go "under" the buttons, here is what i try

```
this.mapView = new MyMapView(this, map_key);
        this.mapView.setClickable(true);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.tipo_mappa);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


        this.mapView.setLayoutParams( p );



        layout.addView(this.mapView, 0);
```

The result is i only see the map in fullscreen, the buttons are hidden/underneath maybe.

This is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMappa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




    <!--

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:apiKey="abc"
        android:clickable="true" />

    -->

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/tipo_mappa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/mappa_normale" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/mappa_satelite" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/traffic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipo_mappa"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:text="@string/mappe_traffic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hav you tried to use `setContentView(this.mapView)` and after that inflate your XML and use `addContentView` ?

Comment: i tried but it keeps crashing, must be doing something wrong

Comment: does the ReqeuestFocus solve your issue? if not please add a StackTrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it'll work, but try requesting focus back to your buttons after adding the map. It might pull them back to the surface.
[View.requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29)